# Generically add children to parents

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I am querying multiple related tables from a database and mapping them to classes. For performance reasons, I am querying each table separately and joining them in my code as opposed to using SQL joins. Doing the joining is rather simple with a `foreach` loop for each level, but it feels redundant, so I've tried abstracting it.

I have a base class `Entity` and two interfaces, `IParent` and `IChild`:

```
public abstract class Entity<TId> : IEquatable<Entity<TId>>
{
    public TId Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IParent<TParent, TParentId, TChild, TChildId>
    where TChild : Entity<TChildId>, IChild<TChild, TChildId, TParent, TParentId>
    where TParent : Entity<TParentId>, IParent<TParent, TParentId, TChild, TChildId>
{
    ICollection<TChild> Children { get; set; }
}

public interface IChild<TChild, TChildId, TParent, TParentId> 
    where TParent : Entity<TParentId>, IParent<TParent, TParentId, TChild, TChildId>
    where TChild : Entity<TChildId>, IChild<TChild, TChildId, TParent, TParentId>
{
    TParent Parent { get; set; }

    TParentId ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Entity represents an abstraction of a database table, with parent being the one and child being the many in a one-to-many relationship. I have written `AddChildren` methods like these:

```
public partial class Helpers
{
    public static void AddChildren<TParent, TParentId, TChild, TChildId>(
        IDictionary<TParentId, TParent> parents,
        IList<TChild> children)
        where TParent : Entity<TParentId>, IParent<TParent, TParentId, TChild, TChildId>
        where TChild : Entity<TChildId>, IChild<TChild, TChildId, TParent, TParentId>
    {
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            parents[child.ParentId].Children.Add(child);
        }
    }

    public static void AddChildren<T1, T1Id, T2, T2Id, T3, T3Id>(
        IDictionary<T1Id, T1> t1,
        IDictionary<T2Id, T2> t2,
        IList<T3> t3)
        where T1 : Entity<T1Id>, IParent<T1, T1Id, T2, T2Id>
        where T2 : Entity<T2Id>, IChild<T2, T2Id, T1, T1Id>, IParent<T2, T2Id, T3, T3Id>
        where T3: Entity<T3Id>, IChild<T3, T3Id, T2, T2Id>
    {
        AddChildren<T2, T2Id, T3, T3Id>(t2, t3);
        AddChildren<T1, T1Id, T2, T2Id>(t1, t2.Values.ToList());
    }
}
```

I'm not particularly thrilled with having to specify all the type parameters whenever I implement the interfaces and call the methods. Simple classes look like this:

```
public class MyGuidParentEntity : Entity<System.Guid>, IParent<MyGuidParentEntity, System.Guid, MyLongChildEntity, long>
{
    public ICollection<MyLongChildEntity> Children { get; set; }
}

public class MyLongChildEntity : Long.Entity, IChild<MyLongChildEntity, long, MyGuidParentEntity, System.Guid>
{
    public MyGuidParentEntity Parent { get; set; }

    public System.Guid ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Simple method invocations look like this:

```
Helpers.AddChildren<MyGuidParentEntity, System.Guid, MyLongChildEntity, long>(parents, children);
```

Is there any way to shorten/remove the generic type arguments? If not from the class declarations, then from the `AddChildren` methods? I'd love to be able to do `AddChildren(parents, children)` and have the types sorted out. Even `AddChildren<TParent, TChild>(parents, children)` would be an improvement.

Alternatively, is there a better way to go about this problem? Am I shooting myself in the foot by trying to abstract things too much?

Comment: ◾ *Is there any way to simplify the generic arguments?* → Simplify like what? With what cost, loosing some constraints or loosing some functionalities?

Comment: ◾ *Should I be doing something different altogether?* → You shared your solution, but didn't say anything about the requirement you are trying to satisfy.

Comment: Is this a code review?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have rewritten portions of the question to hopefully clarify what exactly I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Nkosi I've edited the question to be better suited for a code review.

Comment: Maybe you're using the wrong technology, maybe something like GraphQL will do a neater job at satisfying your requirements.

Comment: _For performance reasons, I am querying each table separately and joining them in my code as opposed to using SQL joins._ => That buffles me! So what is going to happen when you have millions of records in 3 tables that you need to join? Get them all into memory, join objects?

Comment: Pulling all the data from the server across the network to join them in memory is a terrible idea, don't do it.  SQL is there to do all the work on the server, and then just the data you actually need is sent across the network.

Answer (score 0):

In essence your question seems to be about how to get rid of generic arguments as you go through the process of developing additional methods and derived classes.

Carrying around all of the generic type arguments gives you a great deal of type strength. But clearly this comes at a cost in ease of use. You can increase the ease of use by reducing the type strength a little bit.

One way to do it would be to introduce an interface, like this:

```
public interface IEntity: IEquatable<IEntity>
{
    // ...
}

public class Entity<TId,TChild>: IEntity
where TChild: IEntity
{
    public TId Id { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<TChild> Children { get; } = new Collection<TChild>();
    // ...
}
```

Another approach also might make sense, depending on your situation. That would be to define the parent/child relationships separately from the nodes. Like this:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    // ...
}

public class Entity<TId>: IEntity
{
    public TId Id { get; private set; }
    public Type ChildrenType { get; private set; }
    // ... 
}

public static class Tree
{
    static private Dictionary<IEntity, ICollection<IEntity>> ChildCollections = new Dictionary<IEntity, ICollection<IEntity>>();
    static private Dictionary<IEntity, IEntity> Parents = new Dictionary<IEntity,IEntity>();

    static public ICollection<IEntity> GetChildren(this IEntity parent) => Tree.ChildCollections.ContainsKey(parent) ? this.ChildCollections[parent] : null;
    static public IEntity GetParent(this IEntity child) => Tree.Parents.ContainsKey(child) ? this.Parents[child] : null;

    static public void AddChild<TParentId,TChildId>( this Entity<TParentId> parent, Entity<TChildId> child)
    {
        if (!parent.ChildrenType.IsAssignableFrom(child.GetType())) { throw new InvalidOperationException("Child is not of correct type"); }

        if (Tree.Parents.ContainsKey(child)) { throw new InvalidOperationException("Child already has a parent"); }
        Tree.Parents.Add(child, parent);

        if (!Tree.ChildCollections.ContainsKey(parent)) {
            Tree.ChildCollections.Add(parent, new Collection<IEntity>());
        }
        Tree.ChildCollections[parent].Add(child);
    }
    static public void RemoveChild( this IEntity parent, IEntity child)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```